# Break my source file!

Tags: code-golf, source-layout

## Challenge

Create a program that, when run, changes the contents of the source file. This means that you can delete/add/change characters in the source file, but you can't delete the (source) file itself (deletion is when the source file does not exist after the program is run).

In the case of pre-compiled languages such as C++, your program can change the source file only, such that when compiled, either fails or does not produce the same result.

Your program must not return any errors, such as access violations (e.g. opening a file that is already open).

- This is an advantage to pre-compiled languages, as the source file does not have to be in use to run it.

### Input

You may take an optional path to the source file, but nothing more.

### Output

You may output anything.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins!

Comment: The title and the clarification for compiled languages suggest that the modification should stop the program from working afterwards, but the actual rules in your first paragraph make no mention of that.

Comment: @MartinEnder, the second paragraph suggests that the program must fail or the _output must be different_ (which can be considered breaking it, since it no longer produces the output it used to).

Comment: @LuisMendo Probably fixed

Comment: Yes, I think it's better now

Comment: Can we assume the file name is a fixed string, such as `f`?

Comment: Can you hard code the file name and location?

Comment: Hi there! I've dupe-hammered this closed because even though the linked challenge is a popcon and this is a code-golf, many of the answers there are also valid and contenders here. Thanks!

Comment: @AdmBorkBork This question is about changing the source file. The dup is about damaging the program itself or the environment. That is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Notts90 Yes, as long as it works. Hell, put it in /bin/ if you like.

Comment: Re: the "is this a duplicate?" arguments: I immediately thought of Vigil for answering this question, looked at the duplicate that was linked, and saw Vigil as the top answer on +438. That said, many of the other answers won't transfer over; I guess this challenge is a subset of that one, rather than an exact copy, and am not sure how the duplicate rules apply to that.

Answer (score 10):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 3 bytes

```sh
>$0
```

Truncates the script to length **0**.

Unlike its Bash counterpart, this handles filenames that contain whitespace.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/zsh#@5@XmJtqq55bqVBQlJ9elJirV5yhzpWanJGvoJunoG6nYqCuYKegAlIFEXVydfMPcuWqqEhR0E1XMIRKlScr6CZD2VXFGcgaHN1CXIPwqP//HwA)

Answer (score 7):

## C, <s>35</s> 25 bytes

```c
f(){fopen(__FILE__,"w");}
```

Just empties the source file.

[Online test suite on TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S04sUbBTSM5PSdVLVrCxUXD1d/ufpqFZnZZfkJqnER/v5unjGh@vo1SupGld@z83MTMPJKkB5HABlXJxpSZn5Cs4pablF6UqpFakJpeWZObnWXElA42FGApWwcWVnpwMs0U3H6ySS08fTEGMcEwrSS3CbsJ/AA)

Comment: `but you can't delete the file itself.` Clarification: the "file" in question is the source file.

Comment: @Thunda source file doesn't get deleted, it just gets emptied so it can't be compiled again.

Comment: I'd correct the "erase" term anyway.

Comment: Erase was a bit ambiguous there

Comment: I agree - I wasn't quite awake.

Answer (score 5):

## Octave, 27 bytes

```
fwrite(fopen('f','w'),'')
```

**Explanation:**

`fopen('f','w')` opens the file `f` (itself) with writing privileges (the file has no file extension (it's not `f.m`)). `fwrite` writes an empty string `''` to that file, overwriting the content of it.

Run it from the GUI / CLI using: `run f`. PS!

Note: You should close the file again afterwards using `fclose(3)`, but this is not necessary for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
open(input(),"w")
```

-1 thanks to @EriktheOutgolfer

Opens itself in write mode, deleting everything in the file.

Comment: You can use `input()` getting quoted input (Python 2) or non-quoted input (Python 3) to the file path, because it's allowed by the rules. That saves 1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
“µ÷ⱮÑċẊṚ⁾Ṁ)ɦGl»ŒV
```

Never fails, but produces different outputs.

Takes relative path through STDIN (unquoted).

Explanation:

```
“µ÷ⱮÑċẊṚ⁾Ṁ)ɦGl»ŒV Main link. Arguments: 0
“µ÷ⱮÑċẊṚ⁾Ṁ)ɦGl»   Literal "open(input(),'w')"
               ŒV Python eval and listify
```

Open a file in write mode in Python overwrites it.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 18

```
fopen(__FILE__,w);
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

```
Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning 
of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file 
does not exist, attempt to create it.
```

I guess that should also work in most other languages

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 10 bytes

```ruby
open $0,?w
```

Not very original, almost everybody is doing it the same way nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

### C, 27 bytes

```
f(){system("cd>"__FILE__);}
```

Overwrites the contents of the file wtih the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, <s>7</s> 4 bytes

<sub><sup>Thanks to Neil for saving 3 bytes</sup></sub>

```
.>%0
```

`>` overwrites the contents of a file and `%0` returns the current batch file's path.
Result: Blank batch file.

Comment: `.` is shorter than `FC` and still seems to work. I like the `~f` but I would have thought you're allowed to require that the batch file is invoked including extension.

Comment: @Neil Indeed, thanks. I took another look and this might be the limit for Batch.

Answer (score 0):

## Node.js, 47 bytes

```
require('fs').writeFileSync(process.argv[1],'')
```

Erase the content of the source file